# Return only rows where column values has changed

Tags: sql

I am trying the below query but returning me 67 rows.
But I want the values only when the "Is entity a PEP" value has changed.

```
select tpe.extrnl_id_val as "CE",
CASE WHEN tc.POLICALLY_EXPOSED_PERSON_IND=1 THEN (select 'Yes' from dual)
ELSE (select 'No' from dual) END as "Is this entity a PEP",
tc.upd_ts as "Date"
from rkyc_em_01.tclient_jrnl tc,rkyc_em_01.tparty_extrnl_id tpe
where tc.party_id=tpe.party_id
and extrnl_id_val in ('1231554')
group by POLICALLY_EXPOSED_PERSON_IND, extrnl_id_val,tc.upd_ts
order by tc.upd_ts desc
```

OUTPUT:

```
CE        PEP   Date
1231554   Yes   10/20/2016 11:52:36 AM
1231554   Yes   10/20/2016 11:52:24 AM
1231554   Yes   10/20/2016 11:50:11 AM
1231554   Yes   10/14/2016 10:38:30 AM
1231554   No    8/18/2016 10:35:51 AM
1231554   No    7/25/2016 3:22:05 AM
1231554   No    2/17/2016 1:58:40 AM
1231554   No    10/9/2015 3:23:54 AM
1231554   No    6/26/2015 10:33:02 AM
1231554   No    6/16/2015 7:43:23 AM
1231554   No    6/27/2014 4:51:19 PM
1231554   No    2/25/2014 9:42:21 AM
1231554   No    2/18/2014 9:27:30 AM
1231554   No    12/12/2013 9:29:10 AM
1231554   No    11/25/2013 6:56:23 AM
1231554   No    5/31/2013 7:37:32 AM
1231554   No    5/31/2013 7:37:27 AM
1231554   No    3/27/2013 8:09:45 PM
1231554   No    3/4/2013 5:33:02 PM
1231554   No    12/10/2012 7:46:33 PM
1231554   No    9/24/2012 8:47:30 PM
1231554   No    9/24/2012 8:47:22 PM
1231554   No    11/21/2011 11:32:28 AM
1231554   No    11/21/2011 11:32:27 AM
1231554   No    11/18/2011 3:48:04 PM
1231554   No    8/6/2011 1:10:14 PM
1231554   No    8/6/2011 7:09:18 AM
1231554   No    8/6/2011 6:46:55 AM
```

Expected Output:

```
CE        PEP   Date
1231554   Yes   10/14/2016 10:38:30 AM
1231554   No    8/6/2011 6:46:55 AM
```

Comment: Share your expected output.

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY`? You are not aggregating anything. Is this merely to mean `DISTINCT`? If so, what makes you get duplicates? Multiple matches in `tc` or in `tpe` or both? Will you always be looking for only one `extrnl_id_val`? What is your DBMS? And: you shouldn't use those pre-1992 comma-separated joins anymore.

Comment: Hey Thorsten,   I have updated the query with distinct. and no I wont always be looking for one extrnl_id_val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do this in standard SQL. You look into the previous record with `LAG` to see if there is a change.

```
select 
  extrnl_id_val as "ce",
  case when current_value = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as "is this entity a pep",
  upd_ts as "date"
from
(
  select 
    tpe.extrnl_id_val,
    tc.upd_ts,
    tc.polically_exposed_person_ind as current_value,
    lag(tc.polically_exposed_person_ind) over (partition by tpe.extrnl_id_val 
                                               order by tc.upd_ts desc) as previous_value
  from rkyc_em_01.tclient_jrnl tc
  join rkyc_em_01.tparty_extrnl_id tpe using(party_id)
  where tpe.extrnl_id_val in ('1231554')
)
where current_value <> previous_value or previous_value is null
order by upd_ts desc;
```

Comment: Hi Thorsten Kettner, Thanks for this but I wanted the value which got changed but with this I am getting the latest value which is now. This query is giving me 6 rows. can you please see my expected output and help. Appreciate your help. Many Thanks

Comment: I saw your expected output and was sure my query would produce it. I must admit, I don't see how it can not produce the desired output. The query looks at each ID ordered by date and detects changes to the previous record. That should work. Can you show me the six rows?

Comment: I just ran a small test on my DBMS (with one table instead of two containing your sample records) and the query works just fine. There was a typo with a double `as`, which I've corrected, but that wouldn't have led to wrong results, but a syntax error instead.

Comment: 1231554 no 8/6/2011 6:46:55 AM
1231554 no 8/6/2011 7:09:18 AM
1231554 no 8/18/2016 10:35:51 AM
1231554 yes 10/20/2016 11:52:36 AM    I just added distinct after first select to make the row count 4 but it is still not what exactly I want . can you please check and help.

Comment: I don't see how this can happen. You may want to execute the subquery alone (with the order by added), so you see all data. In case there can be rows with `polically_exposed_person_ind` null, you may want to add `and polically_exposed_person_ind is not null`. Sorry, I have no other idea; this is something you must solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT tpe.extrnl_id_val as "CE",
    CASE WHEN tc.POLICALLY_EXPOSED_PERSON_IND=1 THEN 
     (select 'Yes' from dual)
    ELSE 
     (select 'No' from dual) END as "Is this entity a PEP",
    tc.upd_ts AS "Date"
    from rkyc_em_01.tclient_jrnl tc, rkyc_em_01.tparty_extrnl_id tpe
    where tc.party_id = tpe.party_id
    and extrnl_id_val in ('1231554')
    group by POLICALLY_EXPOSED_PERSON_IND, extrnl_id_val,tc.upd_ts
    order by tc.upd_ts desc) T
  WHERE --add your condition here.
```